# How to stop and fully remove any executing javascript from a section of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page structure as following:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

        <span>
            <img src="public/demo.png" />
        </span>

        <span id="removeWithin">

            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Demo Demo</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Demo Demo</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <script type="text/javascript">

            // there is some javascript logic in here...

            </script>

        </span>

    </body>
</html>
```

On a button click I would like to fully remove and stop from executing all of the children within the span tag "removeWithin" (remove all of the HTML code + stop and remove all of the JavaScript code). I would like the page to be as such after removal:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

        <span>
            <img src="public/demo.png" />
        </span>

        <span id="removeWithin">

        </span>

    </body>
</html>
```

How do I do this?

If I use jQuery's empty() will it automatically stop all of the JavaScript code within the span tag from executing?

```
$("#removeWithin").empty();
```

Comment: If the script has already been appended to the page, it's already ran.  Removing the markup really won't affect that at all.  *"If I use jQuery's empty() will it automatically stop all of the JavaScript code within the span tag from executing?"* No.

Comment: Clearing the node can be done with empty(). But for the javascript, you need to remove all the event listeners you use Before removing the nodes they're tied to. Can you show the JS that needs to get removed so we have an idea how many handlers it contains and if it's doable to remove them all? If there's no event handlers ( like click and such ) , you're probably ok with leaving the script in.

Comment: on click: `throw new FatalError("!! Stop JavaScript Execution !!");` seriously i dont think this works